# assigning two 8 bit bitsets to one 16 bit bitset

Tags: c++, bitset

Is there any way I can assign two 8 bit bitsets to one 16 bit bitset
e.g.

```
 bitset<8> first = var1;
 bitset<8> second = var2;
 bitset<16> = first+second;
```

Comment: The following worked which was recommended by a user:        bitset<16> third(first.to_ulong() << first.size() | second.to_ulong()); I don't really understand it but it works

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: I can explain why it works

Answer (score 2):

if you want them to be serialized:

```
bitset<16> result(first.to_ulong() * 0x100 + second.to_ulong());
```

this makes first to the *most significant* and second to *least significant* bits.

Comment: `0xFF` should be `0x100`.

Answer (score 2):

Shift the first bits size over.

This is assuming that first.size() + second.size() is not any bigger than ullong in c++11.

```
bitset<first.size()+second.size()> third(first.to_ullong() << first.size() | second.to_ullong());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not constrained to use bitset<>, you might find that the bit-wise operators are most suitable for such manipulations.  Certainly, it's much more terse, which may or may not be suitable or to your liking.  E.g.,

```
unsigned bit_1 = 0xff,   // low order 8 bits set
         bit_2 = 0xff00, // high order 8 bits set
         bit_3 = 0,
         bit_4 = 0x1ce9;

bit_3 = bit_1 | bit_2;  // now bit_3 has all 16 bits set
bit_3 ^= bit_3;         // every bit that was set is now cleared
bit_3 = bit_4 & bit_1;  // using bit_1 as a mask, bit_3 now contains just the
                        // lower order bits that are set in bit_4, 0xe9
```